# pytest doesn't execute project/__init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

I have the structure of project like:

```
- chats
-     __init__.py
-     messenger.py
- tests
-     test_acs.py
-     __init__.py
```

here is the code in `test_acs.py`:

```
    from chats import messenger
    import asyncio
    import pytest
    import os

    def test_get_last_message():
        os.environ["API_ID"] = 'API_ID'
        os.environ["API_HASH"] = 'API_HASH'

        assert asyncio.new_event_loop().run_until_complete(messenger.get_last_message('PARAM')) == '1'
```

here is the code in `__init__.py`:

```
from os import environ
API_ID = environ.get('API_ID')
API_HASH = environ.get('API_HASH')
```

But when I try to use `API_ID` / `API_HASH` in `messenger.get_last_message()` - python doesn't see them.

I checked and it turns out that pytest doesn't run `chats/__init__.py` at all, which is very strange. Maybe there are ideas? I start tests with `python -m pytest` from root directory.

Comment: Your `__init__.py` is definitely being run, but you haven't imported the symbols.  Do `import chats`.  Now you have `chats.API_ID` and `chats.messenger` available.

Comment: Your `chats` module does get run when imported. However, the assignment `API_ID = environ.get('API_ID')` only happens _once_ at import time. Whatever string get bound to `API_ID` then will stay unchanged, even if you modify `environ["API_ID"]` later on.

Comment: `API_ID` is not an *alias* for `environ['API_ID']`, it just stores the *result* of a `dict` lookup at a particular point in time (and that point in time is before you run your test).